# What method is this of declaring constants in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I have read elsewhere that constants can be created in TCL using the keyword set. However, when I looked at the source code of the math package, I found that the math constants are declared in a different way. Please see the [code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-87/tcl_ext/tcllib/tcllib/modules/math/constants.tcl.auto.html) below:

```
package provide math::constants 1.0.1

# namespace constants
#    Create a convenient namespace for the constants
#
namespace eval ::math::constants {
    #
    # List of constants and their description
    #
    variable constants {
        pi        3.14159265358979323846   "ratio of circle circumference and diameter"
        e         2.71828182845904523536   "base for natural logarithm"
        ln10      2.30258509299404568402   "natural logarithm of 10"
        phi       1.61803398874989484820   "golden ratio"
        gamma     0.57721566490153286061   "Euler's constant"
        sqrt2     1.41421356237309504880   "Square root of 2"
        thirdrt2  1.25992104989487316477   "One-third power of 2"
        sqrt3     1.73205080756887729533   "Square root of 3"
        radtodeg  57.2957795131            "Conversion from radians to degrees"
        degtorad  0.017453292519943        "Conversion from degrees to radians"
        onethird  1.0/3.0                  "One third (0.3333....)"
        twothirds 2.0/3.0                  "Two thirds (0.3333....)"
        onesixth  1.0/6.0                  "One sixth (0.1666....)"
        huge      [find_huge]              "(Approximately) largest number"
        tiny      [find_tiny]              "(Approximately) smallest number not equal zero"
        eps       [find_eps]               "Smallest number such that 1+eps != 1"
    }
    namespace export constants print-constants
}
```

1. Is the "*variable constants*" a dictionary? It appears to be so. But what keyword is *variable*?
2. Why do we need the *namespace eval* and then *namespace export* as well? I mean why not just say namespace ::math::constants once and leave it at that?
3. Why do we need this line *namespace export constants print-constants*?
4. Why not just create the constants using the TCL set command?
5. Is it true that we cannot actually have constants in TCL (like const keyword in C) and that everything can be redefined to whatever we want? Does this not create security issues for this langauge?

Comment: Going to let someone else have a turn to answer, but you might want to read https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/constants for discussion on how to create true constants.

Comment: Tcl doesn't have constants as such. It has other ways to solve those issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is the "variable constants" a dictionary? It appears to be so. But what keyword is variable?

It is not (or it is, but only by accident). Each thing it defines has three *words* in the definition, and dictionaries have strictly two words per mapping entry.

The `variable` command is documented at: https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/variable.htm

> 2. Why do we need the `namespace eval` and then `namespace export` as well? I mean why not just say `namespace ::math::constants` once and leave it at that?
> 3. Why do we need this line `namespace export constants print-constants`?

The `namespace export` defines which *commands* are exported from the namespace, i.e., which ones can be `namespace import`ed  by elsewhere. There is no assumption that all commands are exported. There is no assumption that a namespace exports a command with the same name as itself. Variables aren't exported (but similar effects can be achieved; it's rare to do this between namespaced variables).

*This changes* if you use the defaults in `namespace ensemble` or if you move on to using TclOO. Those *do* make (documented!) default assumptions.

Variables and commands are different things entirely. They use a different space of names (i.e., they have a different hash table in each namespace) and cannot be confused. The `math::constants` package provides a command for doing additional stuff, but that's just a feature of the package and isn't anything general.

Many namespaces never export any commands. That's totally OK. Commands and variables can always be accessed by fully qualified name.

> 4. Why not just create the constants using the TCL `set` command?

You can, in the global namespace. By convention, generic libraries try to leave that alone for Tcl itself (though Tcl also reserves a few namespaces, especially `::tcl`) and for applications, i.e., for your code.

But in a non-root namespace, for seriously ugly reasons that I think are best thought of as a bug, it's best to create variables using the `variable` command. Technically, it's not a bug but rather an *extremely* non-obvious outcome of how variables are resolved, and I hate it very much. (I think it will be gone from Tcl 9.0 when that comes out.) Doing it the other way *might* work, but it might not and you really don't want code that only *might* work in production. The problem occurs when there's an existing variable with the same name in the global namespace… and just UGH!

The difference between `set` and `variable` in this area has been the cause of a number of bugs in Tcl's own packages.

> 5. Is it true that we cannot actually have constants in TCL (like const keyword in C) and that everything can be redefined to whatever we want? Does this not create security issues for this langauge?

Generally speaking, there's no security issues from this. The reasons why are several-fold:

1. Values (not variables) are immutable in their model; if something has a value, it won't be mutated out from under its feet.
2. You can simulate a constant using appropriate traces, but this isn't commonly done. After all, it would still be possible to `unset` the variable and that can't truly be blocked; for example, it *must* work if the containing namespace is being deleted. Once deletion is possible, being a constant cannot be guaranteed.
3. Tcl uses interpreters as its fundamental security boundaries, and the ability to reach from a child interpreter into its parent is extremely strictly controlled, being mainly via either returning a value or calling a cross-interpreter alias command (which is approximately like doing a system call, except much more lightweight). Untrusted code can be run in a context where it can't do damage, and yet have exactly the extra capabilities that you want to give it (and it's up to you to decide how to prevent abuse).

What are the main uses for constants in other languages? Well, there's various types of enumeration (where in Tcl you'd use either the name of the item or a list of names, neither of which can be remapped to something else untoward), and then there special constants like you describe. Those are usually not security tokens, but rather if someone sets `pi` to be `3.0` then they'll just get wrong answers. That's on them!

Tcl does not stop you from causing problems in your own interpreter. You really can do things like replacing `while` and `foreach` and so on (and there are cases where it is useful to do so). But if you get it wrong, all you'll do is cause yourself problems. I once decided to make icon images for all my buttons named after the operation they carried out, and then briefly wondered why every call to `open` a file stopped working. Oh well.

But operations in one interpreter *cannot* affect what happens in another unless that other interpreter gives permission (or if it is operations in a parent interpreter affecting one or more of its children). That's the security domain barrier. Don't evaluate untrusted code in trusted contexts. Just don't.